# PowerShell / Regex - How to add a string after the 7th character to a list of filenames

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a folder with a bunch of filenames I'd like to change.  I'd like to insert a string after the 7th character.

**Current filename:**

- 123456_9999999999999_DocName.pdf
- 234567_9999999999999_DocName.pdf
- 345678_9999999999999_DocName.pdf
- 456789_9999999999999_DocName.pdf

**Desired outcome:**

- 123456_DocType_9999999999999_DocName.pdf
- 234567_DocType_9999999999999_DocName.pdf
- 345678_DocType_9999999999999_DocName.pdf
- 456789_DocType_9999999999999_DocName.pdf

I've tried the following I've pieced together, but it only renames one file and causes an error.

```
$location = 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\TEST' 
Get-ChildItem -Path $location -Recurse | 
    Rename-Item -NewName{$_.name -replace '(.*?)_(.*)', '_DocType_'}
```

How can I insert this string to multiple filenames after the 7th character please?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: `-replace '^.{6}', '$&_DocType'`

Comment: Did any solution work for you in the end?

Answer (score 3):

Note: The commands below focus just on the `-replace` operation; simply substituting the RHS of one of these operations for the RHS of the `-replace` operation in the code in the question is enough - although adding the `-File` switch is advisable to ensure that no accidental attempt to rename *directories* is made.<sup>[1]</sup>

---

To insert literally after the 7th character:

```
PS> '123456_9999999999999_DocName.pdf' -replace '(?<=^.{7})', 'DocType_'
123456_DocType_9999999999999_DocName.pdf
```

<sup>Note: As [filimonic's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66442904/45375) shows, you don't need a *regex* in this simple case; using the `[string]` type's `.Insert()` method is both simpler and faster.</sup>

More flexibly, to insert after the first `_` in the name:

```
PS> '123456_9999999999999_DocName.pdf' -replace '(?<=^[^_]+_)', 'DocType_'
123456_DocType_9999999999999_DocName.pdf
```

Note:

- `(?<=...)` is a positive look-behind *assertion* that matches the *position* of the subexpression represented by `...` here - from the beginning (`^`), either the first 7 characters (`.{7}`), or a nonempty run (`+`) of characters *other than* `_` (`[^_]`) followed by a `_`.
- The replacement string (`'DocType_'`) is therefore *inserted* into (a copy of) the original string at that position.
- The look-behind approach obviates the need to refer to *part of what was captured* by the regex in the replacement operand, such as the use of `$&` in [Wiktor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66442542/45375).

  - Note: While this approach is *convenient* and works well *here*, it has its *pitfalls*, because an anchored-to-the-start (`^`) subexpression *inside a look-behind assertion* doesn't always behave the same as outside of one - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66446285/45375).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) for an overview of PowerShell's `-replace` operator.

---

<sup>[1] If the `-replace` operation turns out to be a no-op (if the regex doesn't match, the input string is returned as-is), trying to rename a *directory* to its *existing name* will actually generate an error, unlike with files - see [GitHub issue #14903](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14903).</sup>

Answer (score 3):

```
'123456_9999999999999_DocName.pdf'.Insert(7,'DocType_')
```

No need any regular expressions. Works twice faster. Self-descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$location = 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\TEST' 
Get-ChildItem -Path $location -Recurse | 
    Rename-Item -NewName{$_.name -replace '^.{6}', '$&_DocType'}
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E.%7B6%7D&i=123456_9999999999999_DocName.pdf%0D%0A234567_9999999999999_DocName.pdf%0D%0A345678_9999999999999_DocName.pdf%0D%0A456789_9999999999999_DocName.pdf&r=%24%26_DocType&o=m).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a string
- `.{6}` - any 6 chars other than LF char.

`$&` in the replacement pattern is the reference to the whole match.

Comment: @JM1 You are welcome. No need using lookbehinds that can be confusing even for some regex gold badge users. Please consider accepting the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

All answers submitted worked for me.

The final code I ended up using is:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $location -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName{$_.name.Insert(7,'DocType_')}
```

For me regex is a bit confusing and this code will make it easier for me and others on my team who may not use regex to support the code moving forward.  I upvoted all answers as they work.  Thanks to all who took time to help me and others who may have the same question.