# Surprising, but correct behavior of a greedy subexpression in a positive lookbehind assertion

Tags: .net, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

**Note**:

- The observed behavior is *correct*, but may at first be *surprising*; it was to me, and I think it may be to others as well - though probably not to those intimately familiar with regex engines.
- The repeatedly suggested duplicate, [Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups), contains *general* information about look-around assertions, but does *not* address the specific misconception at hand, as discussed in more detail in the comments below.

---

Using a *greedy*, by definition *variable-width* subexpression inside a [positive look-behind assertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#zero-width-positive-lookbehind-assertions) can exhibit surprising behavior.

The examples use PowerShell for convenience, but the behavior applies to the .NET regex engine in general:

This command works as I intuitively expect:

```sh
# OK:  
#     The subexpression matches greedily from the start up to and
#     including the last "_", and, by including the matched string ($&) 
#     in the replacement string, effectively inserts "|" there - and only there.
PS> 'a_b_c' -replace '^.+_', '$&|'
a_b_|c
```

The following command, which uses a positive look-behind assertion, `(?<=...)`, is *seemingly* equivalent - but *isn't*:

```sh
# CORRECT, but SURPRISING:
#   Use a positive lookbehind assertion to *seemingly* match
#   only up to and including the last "_", and insert a "|" there.
PS> 'a_b_c' -replace '(?<=^.+_)', '|'
a_|b_|c  # !! *multiple* insertions were performed
```

Why isn't it equivalent? Why were *multiple* insertions performed?

Comment: **This is a duplicate of [Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups) and also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197672/3832970), too.**

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Reposting the same information without addressing the points made to the contrary is unhelpful. The comments on the answer below explain why your links don't help. That the additional link you've posted this time doesn't help either is easily verified by looking for the terms "variable-width", "variable-length", and "greedy" - which _this_ question is about - there: you won't find them.

Comment: Just to spare future readers potentially wasted effort, and to balance the shouting in the comment above: **The alleged duplicate(s) _generically_ describe the behavior of look-around assertions. They do _not_ address this question's _specific misconception_**. While you can hypothetically _infer_ the explanation from the linked posts, such an inference is far from obvious. **Only the answer below provides a specific, (hopefully) clear explanation**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**tl;dr**:

- **Inside a *look-behind assertion*, a *greedy* subexpression *in effect* behaves *non-greedily* (in *global* matching *in addition to* acting greedily)**, due to considering *every prefix string* of the input string.

---

My problem was that **I hadn't considered that, in a look-behind assertion,  *each and every* character position in the input string must be checked for the *preceding text up to that point*** to match the subexpression in the lookbehind assertion.

This, combined with the always-global replacement that PowerShell's `-replace` operator performs (that is, *all* possible matches are performed), resulted in *multiple* insertions:

That is, **the greedy, anchored subexpression `^.+_` legitimately matched *twice***, when considering the *text to the left of the character position currently being considered*:

- First, when `a_` was the text to the left.
- And again when `a_b_` was the text to the left.

Therefore, *two* insertions of `|` resulted.

---

By contrast, *without* a look-behind assertion, greedy expression  `^.+_` by definition only matches *once*, through to the *last* `_`, because it is only applied to the *entire input string*.

Comment: This is a [known lookaround behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197608/fixed-length-regex-required/11197672#11197672). No need to repeat it. This is also part of the [Regex FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew re your links: the FAQ (undoubtedly a good general resource) merely links to the first linked answer, which is about _non-support for variable-width patterns_ in lookbehind assertions in Python. By contrast, _this_ question is precisely about _variable-width_ patterns, and it is precisely that variable-width nature that gave rise to the misconception exhibited in my question. The only reference in the FAQ to variable-width lookbehinds is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20994257/45375), which merely states that .NET does support them in general.

Comment: In short: The behavior _isn't_ described in the links you've posted  - not in any meaningful way that would clear up the specific misconception at hand.
This answer now does describes it, and it will hopefully clear up the misconception for others too.